# How to pass integers values to a C program executable file through shell script?

Tags: c, linux, shell, testing

I want to write a simple shell script to automate running 5 test cases for a C program that prints the 3 inputted integers in ascending order.

My shell script looks like:

```
./a.out << 15 25 97
./a.out < 73 36 12
./a.out < 43 15 99
./a.out < 100 100 100
./a.out < 37 150 37
```

Clearly, this is wrong because I have been playing around with the syntax and trying different things to see what works but I hope it is clear what I am trying to do here -- Just running the program with 3 different integer inputs every time.

The one method that I tried and worked is putting each of my test cases in a text file but it seems like a bit of a hassle to do that if I want to change the input every time. Looking for a simpler concise solution.

The input reading snippet of the C program is:

```
int main() {
  int m, n, p;
  //Read m, n, p
  printf("Give values of m, n and p = ");
  scanf("%d%d%d",&m,&n, &p);
```

The values of m, n and p are then used for calculation.

Comment: try `./a.out 545`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your C program so what we can see which method of geting info it expects.

Comment: On a side note: choose your test cases systematically, not arbitrarily, and make it easy to tell right from wrong. Does testing `15 25 97` provide any information that `1 2 3` doesn't? Does your code depend on the magnitude of the numbers?

Comment: Another note: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're asking specifically about their differences.

Comment: @imtryin123 : You can only pass strings as argument to a new process, but C has a standard function `atoi`, where you can convert the string to an integer. However, you forgot to declare the arguments to your `main` function. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765686/correctly-declaring-the-main-function-in-ansi-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correctly declaring the main() function in ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765686/correctly-declaring-the-main-function-in-ansi-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` and `>` do redirection from and to *files*, not from strings.

`|` creates a pipeline between processes, and `echo` outputs to standard output.

You want the pattern

```
echo 1 2 3 | program
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the numbers with scanf, you can use Bash here-strings:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out <<< "15 25 97"
./a.out <<< "73 36 12"
```

You can also change your program to read arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int m, n, p;
  if (argc<4) {
    printf("Not enough numbers\n");
    return 1;
  }
  m=atoi(argv[1]);
  n=atoi(argv[2]);
  p=atoi(argv[3]);
}
```

and then run `./a.out 15 25 97`

Answer (score 0):

> inputted integers

These are for most shells and called programs not integers(, yet). You missed the special `<<<` operator:

```
$ cat <<<"1 2 3"
1 2 3
```

Or like commented:  `echo 1 2 3 | cat`

This is reading **standard input** like a file content. (From `cat`'s perspective). A more useful example:

```
$ bc <<<"1+2"
3
```

---

`cat 1 2 3` gives `No such file` three times. But your `a.out` could be expecting 3 or more whitespace separated "words" that can be converted to C integers. Just like `cat` expects filenames there to convert to their contents.

That is passing command line **arguments**. The program reads an array of strings filled by the shell.

---

Cf. `cpio -o` archiving command. With the only non-optional (besides one of -o create or -i extract or -p) argument it is:

```
cpio -o < name-list
```

This seems unpractical first. No filenames as arguments, only a compulsory file. But the idea is that:

```
find ... | cpio -o >bu.cpio
```

is better than:

```
cpio -o $(find ...) >bu.cpio
```

Or: `|` is simpler than `xargs`.

Cfcf. `tar` for the *other* approach.